# Finding the side and angle of a triangle.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle

I'm working on some summer problems so that I can be more prepared when I go into my class in the fall. I found a website full of problems of the content we will be learning but it doesn't have the answers. I need a little guidance on how to do this problem.

The following diagram shows the triangle $ABC$. 
[image: picture of triangle]

a. Find $AC$.

b. Find $\angle BCA$.

For a, I believe I would do the Pythagorean Theorem to find the side. $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$. Is this correct?

For b, to find this angle would I use the sides? As in using soh-cah-toa?  So, I could do the sine of $6$ over the hypotenuse, which I would find after part a.

Edit: After reading comments, I used the Law of Cosines for part a and got b = 12.5 as my answer. However, I am not sure I completed it correctly.
I also used the Law of Sines to do part b, I got C = 28.16° as my answer. Can someone please tell me if I completed these two correctly?

Comment: no. part (a) is the Law of Cosines. After that, the Law of Sines gives you the other angles

Comment: . . . such as [this](http://mathematics.laerd.com/maths/trigonometry-sine-and-cosine-rules-intro.php). Pythagoras applies to right triangles. Plenty of other sources are available.

Comment: Please read this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), which explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  You cannot apply the Pythagorean Theorem here since you do not have a right triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\displaystyle  \sqrt{(36 + 100 - ((2 * 6 * 10)* \cos{(100)}))}$

$=\displaystyle 12.5235$

$\displaystyle \sin^{-1} \left(\frac{6 * \sin(100)}{12.5235}   \right)$

$=\displaystyle 28.16°$

You can check the answers here:
[enter link description here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt%20(36%20%2B%20100%20-%20((2%20*%206%20*%2010)*%20cos(100))))

[enter link description here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin%5E(-1)%20((6*%20sin(100))%2F12.52))

Answer (score 1):

$\text{ We can also do this. We know through sine law: }$
$\displaystyle \frac{AC}{\sin(\angle{ABC})} = \frac{AB}{\sin(\angle{BCA})}$

$\displaystyle \angle{BCA} = \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{AB * \sin(\angle{ABC})}{AC}\right)$

Comment: I got C=28.16°. Does this seem correct?

Comment: $C=28.15°$ would be slightly better, because it is not affected by the rounding to a three digit  number of $b$.

Comment: Here's the cosine law: https://www.google.ca/search?q=cosine+law&oq=cosine+law&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2430j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 1):

For $a$ we can't use Pythagorean Theorem since ABC is not a right triangle but we need the **[Law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines)**.

For that see the related [Does the law of cosines contradict Pythagoras's theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2659982/505767)

For point b once we have AC by the [**Law of sines**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) we have

$$\frac{\sin 100}{AC}=\frac{\sin (\angle BCA)}{AB}$$